How to Choose Dynamics Options for Dynamic Pipes?
Below is a model of two parallel flows exchanging heat through convection with varying boundary conditions.

The model works fine with steady-state options, which means the mass flow in the pipes is constant. However, the model does not work well with the other options such as "dynamicFreeInitial" etc.
In fact, while the initialization problem is managed correctly with the homotopy method, I encounter a warning indicating that the system is underdetermined.

Additionally, when adding components to this system and using "Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.FixedInitial" options, the software gets stuck at 0%. even if the initialization is handed correctly.
Questions :
1- Why do I get the warning that the system is under-determined when using "Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.FixedInitial"?
2- Is it normal, based on your experience, to have a significant difference in simulation time when using steady-state options compared to FixedInitial options?
code :
model Model
  import Modelica.Constants.pi;
  parameter Integer nNodes = 2;
  parameter Real d = 11e-3;
  parameter Real D = 18e-3;
  parameter Real P_start_1 = 10e+5;
  parameter Real P_start_2 = 153e+5;
  parameter Real T_start_1 = 55 + 273.15;
  parameter Real T_start_2 = 38 + 273.15;
  parameter Real S_conv_1 = 0.4;
  parameter Real S_conv_2 = 0.3;
  parameter Real he = 648;
  parameter Real h_conv_1 = 300;
  parameter Real h_conv_2 = 100;
  parameter Real L1 = 1400e-3;
  parameter Real L2 = 1300e-3;
  parameter Real k_conv_1 = h_conv_1*S_conv_1;
  parameter Real k_conv_2 = S_conv_2*h_conv_2;
  replaceable package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWaterOnePhase constrainedby Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium;
  replaceable model HeatTransfer_1 = Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.HeatTransfer.ConstantFlowHeatTransfer(alpha0 = 5000);
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT Inlet_2(redeclare package Medium = Medium, T = 311.15, nPorts = 1, p = 1074000, use_T_in = false) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-258, 54}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_3(redeclare package Medium = Medium, redeclare final model HeatTransfer = HeatTransfer_1, diameter = d, length = L1, nNodes = nNodes, use_HeatTransfer = true, p_a_start = P_start_1, p_b_start = P_start_1, T_start = T_start_1, m_flow_start = 2.5) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-162, 54}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = -180)));
  inner Modelica.Fluid.System system(T_start(displayUnit = "degC"), m_flow_start = 0.05, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.FixedInitial, massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.FixedInitial) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-258, -1}, extent = {{-12, -11}, {12, 11}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Examples.HeatExchanger.BaseClasses.WallConstProps wall_1(area_h = 0.6, c_wall = 500, k_wall = 14.4, n = nNodes, rho_wall = 7850, s = 3.1e-3, T_start = 311.15, dT = 273.15) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-162, 30}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T outlet_2(redeclare package Medium = Medium, T = 318.15, nPorts = 1, use_T_in = true, use_m_flow_in = true, m_flow = -0.208333333) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-82, 54}, extent = {{10, 10}, {-10, -10}})));
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components.Convection convection_serpentin_1[nNodes] annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-162, 6}, extent = {{-10, 10}, {10, -10}}, rotation = -90)));
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components.ThermalCollector thermalCollector(m = nNodes) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-162, -20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant A_1[nNodes](each k = 50) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-194, 6}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_2(redeclare package Medium = Medium, diameter = 0.1, length = 130e-3, modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.a_v_b, nNodes = 1, use_HeatTransfer = true, isCircular = false, p_a_start = P_start_2, p_b_start = P_start_2, crossArea = Modelica.Constants.pi*(0.474^2 - 0.215^2), perimeter = Modelica.Constants.pi*(0.948 + 0.430), roughness = 3.500000000000001e-05, T_start = T_start_2, m_flow_start = 0.25) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-122, -50}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_1(redeclare package Medium = Medium, diameter = 0.1, length = 130e-3, modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.a_v_b, nNodes = 1, use_HeatTransfer = true, p_a_start = P_start_2, p_b_start = P_start_2, isCircular = false, crossArea = Modelica.Constants.pi*(0.460^2 - 0.200^2), perimeter = Modelica.Constants.pi*(0.900 + 0.415), roughness = 3.500000000000001e-05, T_start = T_start_2, m_flow_start = 0.25) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-162, -50}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T outlet_1(redeclare package Medium = Medium, nPorts = 1, use_T_in = true, use_m_flow_in = true, m_flow = -0.25, T = 318.15) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-88, -50}, extent = {{10, 10}, {-10, -10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT inlet_1(redeclare package Medium = Medium, T = 328.15, nPorts = 1, use_T_in = false, use_p_in = false, p = 15300000) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-256, -50}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sensors.TemperatureSensor temperatureSensor annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-44, -42}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.TimeTable flow_outlet_1(table = [0, -0.05; 116, -0.2475; 128, -0.2052; 136, -0.1647; 144, -0.1287; 152, -0.0972; 158, -0.0756; 164, -0.0549; 264, -0.01; 600, -0.01]) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-44, -78}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.TimeTable Flow_outlet_2(table = [0, -0.05; 68, -0.15833333; 74, -0.14166667; 80, -0.12; 108, -0.033; 122, -0.01875; 136, -0.009; 144, -0.006; 164, -0.00083333; 524, -0.00083333; 530, -0.027; 534, -0.051; 538, -0.07575; 548, -0.11925; 558, -0.14625; 570, -0.168; 586, -0.1815; 600, -0.1875]) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-36, 20}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sensors.TemperatureSensor temperatureSensor1 annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-44, 50}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe(length = 0.1, diameter = 0.1, redeclare package Medium = Medium, p_a_start = P_start_1, p_b_start = P_start_1)  annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-210, 54}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe1(redeclare package Medium = Medium, diameter = 0.1, length = 0.1, p_a_start = P_start_1, p_b_start = P_start_1) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-122, 54}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
equation
  connect(outlet_2.T_in, temperatureSensor1.T) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-70, 50}, {-54, 50}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(pipe_3.heatPorts, wall_1.heatPort_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-162, 50}, {-162.5, 50}, {-162.5, 35}, {-162, 35}}, color = {127, 0, 0}, thickness = 0.5));
  connect(wall_1.heatPort_a, convection_serpentin_1.solid) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-162, 25}, {-162, 16}}, color = {191, 0, 0}, thickness = 0.5));
  connect(A_1.y, convection_serpentin_1.Gc) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-183, 6}, {-178, 6}}, color = {0, 0, 127}, thickness = 0.5));
  connect(convection_serpentin_1.fluid, thermalCollector.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-162, -4}, {-162, -10}}, color = {191, 0, 0}, thickness = 0.5));
  connect(thermalCollector.port_b, pipe_1.heatPorts[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-162, -30}, {-162, -46}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
  connect(outlet_2.m_flow_in, Flow_outlet_2.y) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-72, 46}, {-72, 20}, {-47, 20}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(outlet_1.T_in, temperatureSensor.T) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-76, -54}, {-68, -54}, {-68, -42}, {-54, -42}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(outlet_1.m_flow_in, flow_outlet_1.y) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-78, -58}, {-78, -79.5}, {-55, -79.5}, {-55, -78}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(pipe_2.heatPorts[1], temperatureSensor.port) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-122, -46}, {-122, -25.6}, {-21.9, -25.6}, {-21.9, -42}, {-34, -42}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
  connect(pipe_3.heatPorts[nNodes], temperatureSensor1.port) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-198, 50}, {-130, 50}, {-130, 76}, {32, 76}, {32, 50}, {16, 50}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
  connect(inlet_1.ports[1], pipe_1.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-246, -50}, {-172, -50}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe_2.port_b, outlet_1.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-112, -50}, {-98, -50}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe_1.port_b, pipe_2.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-152, -50}, {-132, -50}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Inlet_2.ports[1], pipe.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-248, 54}, {-220, 54}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe.port_b, pipe_3.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-200, 54}, {-172, 54}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe_3.port_b, pipe1.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-152, 54}, {-132, 54}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe1.port_b, outlet_2.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-112, 54}, {-92, 54}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
algorithm

  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.3")),
    Diagram(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-280, 80}, {-20, -100}}, initialScale = 0.1)),
    Icon(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-1000, -205}, {425, 100}})),
    version = "");
end Model;


I am only familiar with the Fluid Models in IBPSA or Buildings/AixLib, but here you can specify Initial conditions for each component. However, your Model Looks Singular as you Set negative mass flow Rates and fix Temperatures based on the measured Temperatures. What ist the reason for this Setup?

If you define a negative flow in the flow boundary condition, the flow will automatically be positive at the fluid port, if I am not mistaken. The issue was that the system was poorly conditioned. When using the dynamic option, OpenModelica utilizes the initial values defined in the system. Therefore, if the boundary conditions are significantly different from these initial values (for example, if the initial temperature is 20°C and the boundary condition is 100°C), the system struggles to initialize the problem.
